# How to generate dynamic legend using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I used this  [example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tutorial_Advanced_high_quality_web_map_printing_exporting_using_arcpy_mapping/0154000005z2000000/) to produce printing service. As the result I get map with too many elements in the legend. Is it possible ti show classes that are visible in the current map extent using python script?